# Access VM in imported object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**Having a component like so:**

```
import { someData } from 'someData.js'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            foo: 'bar',
            someData: someData
        }
    }
}
```

**someData.js :**

```
export const someData = {
    someObject: {
        test: this.foo // How can I access foo from the component, where this object is imported from? This is not accessable.
    },
}
```

How can I access this.foo in someData.js ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. What do you need this for?

Comment: The component is fetching some analytics data. The someData.js is a highcharts configuration object, that needs to fetch those analytics data, from a computed property in the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export a function instead, and pass the value as an argument:

```
import { getSomeData } from 'someData.js'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            foo: 'bar',
            someData: getSomeData('bar')
        }
    }
}
```

`someData.js`

```
export const getSomeData = foo => ({
    someObject: {
        test: foo
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, the `someData` object is constructed before the `data()` method will be called. You will need to make it a function as well, and accept the `foo` as a parameter:

```
export function makeSomeData(foo) {
    return {
        someObject: {
            test: foo
        },
    };
}
```

```
import { makeSomeData } from 'someData.js'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            foo: 'bar',
            someData: makeSomeData(this.foo)
        }
    }
}
```

That still doesn't exactly work with [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/1048572). You will either need to make it a getter function, or invoke it after constructing the object with the `foo` property:

```
export default {
    data() {
        var obj = {
            foo: 'bar',
        };
        obj.someData = makeSomeData(obj.foo);
        return obj;
    }
}
```